# Calculating the rank and the order of block matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I was trying to learn about matrix blocks and I came across with the following question while practicing: Let $A$ be a matrix of $4\times 5$ with rank of $3$ Consider the following two matrix:

$$B_{1}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & A\\
A^{t} & 0
\end{pmatrix},\,B_{2}=\begin{pmatrix}A & 0 & A\\
0 & A & 2A\\
A & 0 & A
\end{pmatrix}$$

How can I calculate the rank and the order of those matrices?

Comment: first of all how is the rank of a matrix related to the rows/columns of a matrix? Understanding this will help you immensely in answering the question

Comment: @peek-a-boo The rank is all the rows minus the rows with zeros no?

Comment: In general, the rank of a matrix is the maximum number of linearly independent rows. It is also useful to know that $\text{rank}(A) = \text{rank}(A^t)$. With this can you figure out how many rows of $B_1$ are linearly independent? Do the same for $B_2$.

Comment: I think that $B_1$ has rank of $6$ is it correct? $B_2$ is quite difficult, how do I count it? Also, is it correct to say that the order of $B_1$ is $8\times 10$ and the order of $B2$ is $12\times 15$?

Comment: yes $B_1$ has rank $6$. Notice that for $B_2$, the first 4 rows and last 4 rows are exactly the same; thus these are linearly DEPENDENT. So, what can you conclude about the rank? (again, you just need to count the number of linearly independent rows). I got $B_1$ is $9 \times 9$ (treat the size of $A^t$ carefully) and $B_2$ is $12 \times 15$ like you

Comment: We have $\operatorname{rank}(B_1) = \operatorname{rank}(B_2) = 2\operatorname{rank}(A) = 6$

Answer (score 0):

I will consider in the sequel matrix $B_1$ only.

Reasoning on SVD (Singular Value Decomposition) is probably the most direct way.

Let us recall that $4 \times 5$ matrix $A$ can be decomposed in the following way (SVD), which can be seen at least approximatively as an extension of the diagonalization process to general matrices, not especially square) :

$$A=U\Sigma V^T \ \ \ \text{or equivalently} \ \ \ A^T=V\Sigma^T U^T\tag{1}$$

where

- $U$ is a $4 \times 4$ orthogonal matrix,
- $\Sigma$ is $4 \times 5$ (same dimensions as $A$) and
- $V$ is a $5 \times 5$ orthogonal matrix.

The important thing is that $\Sigma$ begins like a diagonal matrix with $3$ non zero diagonal elements $\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3$ in the following way :

$$\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix}\sigma_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \sigma_2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \sigma_3 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\tag{2},$$

Allowing to write

$$B_1=\begin{pmatrix}0 & A\\
A^{T} & 0
\end{pmatrix}=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}U & 0\\
0 & V
\end{pmatrix}}_{\Omega}\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}0 & \Sigma\\
\Sigma^{T} & 0
\end{pmatrix}}_{\Lambda}\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}U^T & 0\\
0 & V^{T}
\end{pmatrix}}_{\Omega^T=\Omega^{-1}}\tag{3}.$$

Therefore, $B_1$ is similar to $\Lambda$ which is clearly a rank-$6$ matrix.